# Multiple Parameters on an IBAction Function

Tags: swift, parameters, ibaction

I currently have a function that gathers a time from a database and returns it for other functions to use. It needs a parameter, which is stored in another part of the app, in order to gather the value from the database.

My problem comes when I want to call this function within an IBAction function.

Here is my code for the function:

```
func getDBValue(place: GMSPlace) -> Int {

    var expectedValue = 0

    databaseRef.child("values").child(place.placeID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let currentValue = snapshot.value as? [Int]

        if currentValue == nil {
            self.noValue()
            expectedValue = 0
        } else {
            let sumValue = currentValue?.reduce(0, +)

            let avgValue = sumValue! / (currentValue?.count)!

            print("The current value is \(String(describing: avgValue))")

            expectedValue = avgValue

            self.valueLabel.text = String(describing: avgValue)
        }

    })

    print("This is the expected WT: \(expectedWaitTime)")

    return expectedValue

}
```

And here is my code for my IBAction function that is having issues with multiple parameters:

```
@IBAction func addValuePressed(_ sender: Any, place: GMSPlace) {

    print("This is the place ID: \(place.placeID)")

    var expectedValue = getDBValue(place: place)

    expectedValue = expectedValue + 1

    print("The expectedValue is now: \(expectedValue)")

    self.valueLabel.text = String(describing: expectedValue)

}
```

This gives me a `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)` error. After some testing, it seems that the error is caused by the added parameter `place: GMSPlace` in my IBAction function. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: You cannot add parameters to an IBAction. Period. The usual workarounds, depending on your needs, are (1) use the tag property (it's an `Int`) to indicate which sender was called, or (2) make your `GMSPlace` instance available inside the IBAction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`IBAction` methods cannot have arbitrary signatures. You cannot add an extra parameter here. There's no way for the button to send you this (how does the button know what `place` is?) Generally this is handled either by there only being one UI element pointing to this action (so you know what button was pressed), or using a `tag` on the sender to identify it. Every view has a `tag` property that's just an integer. You can set that in Interface Builder or in code, and then you can read it to identify the sender.

Start by reading over [Target Action](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html) in the docs that explains how this works on the various platforms. In general, the signature of an `IBAction` must be:

```
@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any)
```

However, on iOS, it may also be:

```
@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any, forEvent: UIEvent)
```

As Taylor M points out below, you can also have use this signature (though I can't remember right off hand if this works outside of iOS; I've only personally used it there).

```
@IBAction func action()
```

But that's it. There are no other allowed signatures.

Comment: You can also have `@IBAction func doSomething()` with no parameters.

Comment: In Xcode 9.2/iOS 11.2, the following signatures also work: 1) `@IBAction func doStuff(_ sender: UIButton)`, i.e. the type of the parameter can be the type of the actual control--the type does not have to be Any.  2) `@IBAction func doStuff(sender: Any)` -- in the Connections Inspector for the ViewController the method name will be listed as doStuffWithSender:.